# Does window.requestAnimationFrame perform threading?

Tags: javascript, html, stack-overflow, requestanimationframe

Does the `window.requestAnimationFrame` function create new threads to let the function where it's called and the function itself run parallel? Because I don't understand why the following code, doesn't result in a stack overflow.

`window.requestAnimationFrame` calls `main` and `main` calls `window.requestAnimationFrame` and so on ...

`w.rAF` -> `main` -> `w.rAF` -> `main` -> `w.rAF` . . .

`main.js`

```
function main(currentTime){
    window.requestAnimationFrame(main);
    console.log(currentTime);
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(main);
```

`index.html`

```
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's almost the same as if you used `setTimeout`. It's just a different queue.

Comment: Thank you, I understand it now. There was already a similar question online. Its just an async function call, im quite familiar with that because of flutter (dart).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`requestAnimationFrame` tells the browser to run the function before the next frame is rendered.
If you again call `requestAnimationFrame` in main it will put that function on the queue for the next (not the current) animationFrame.

In Javascript only workers are threaded.

`requestAnimationFrame` is a special function to execute code at the specific point in the Event Loop. I found this video quite helpful in explaining how the Event Loop works:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0

Answer (score 1):

No. Functions passed to `requestAnimationFrame` are queued, not threaded.

Comment: so why theres no stack overflow? I mean how the `console.log` line is reached then?

Comment: Putting a function on a queue isn't the same as calling the function.